Is this map real?
I recently bought an old treasure map from an antique store with the promise of being able to find the treasure, but when I finally got round to opening it a bunch of scraps fell out and the map was all torn up!!

This isn't any use! And the scraps seem useless too!

Is this a real map? Is there even any treasure?

There's a treasure all right and it's hidden ...

 ... on the northern peninsula of Matsuura Island, a small island off the Western coast of Kyushu, Japan:



 (Link opens Google maps. Yes, that's the island depicted in in the centre of the map I bought. The treasure is in cell K7.)

The map ...

 ... is really a black-and white bitmap where pixels on the underlying 21×21 grid from A1 to U21 are either filled or not. The scraps tell us how the pixels in the missing parts of the map look.

The "Next Gen" scrap:

 This is a state in Conway's Game of Life. We need the the "next gerenation" of that state, which is shown below. (This was found by matt_rule.) The resulting 4×5 bitmap goes into the western part of the map.



The list of numbers separated by pipe symbols:

 These from a nonogram: The six numbers left of the backslash describe the rows, the seven remaining numbers describe the columns. The rows must be read from right to left, or the 1 3 colum won't fit. The resulting 7×6 bitmap goes into the sotern part of the map.


The coordinate tuples:

 These are just that: pairs of coodrinates (x₁, y₁) and (x₂, y₂). They repesent horizontal or vertical lines that are one pixel wide. Both starting and end points are included. The resulting 6×9 bitmap (with a protruding "nose" where x = − 1) goes into the eastern part of the map. The location of the "nose" means the the y-coordinates must be reversed.



The four numbers:

 Represent these as binary numbers. (The bitmap theme suggests this, but if you squint, there's "10 → 2" written in one corner of the scrap.) The resulting 6×4 bitmap goes into the southeastern part of the map.



The letter-number-letter / letter-number-letter combos:

 Stiv got this one: It's a match of battleships played on the 5×5 areas in rows 1–5 and columns I–M and V–Z (off the map) respectively. The last letter in each combo means hit, sunk or miss. The last line means "sunk and won". The hits must be black.)



 The losing party on the left has already the correct coordinates for the northern part of map. The off-map area of the winning party has a hint for the overall solution, on which more later.

The map of the archipelago:

 All squares that have land on them must be black.

This results in:

 

 There are still pieces missing in the nothwest, northeast and southwest corners, but I think you can see now how these parts must be completed.

With the corners filled in:

 

 This is, of course, a QR code. I thought that the noisy nature of the bitmap and the size and position of the last missing pieces made that obvious, but there's also a hint I missed: The hits on the winner of the Battleship match spell QR in Braille. A nice touch.

The answer:

 The given QR code decodes to 松浦島 K7. That's the name of the Matsuura island in Japanese script. That island is represented in our map and K7 refers to the exact location of the treasure.

 (The whole island is not very large, mabe half a kilometre in diameter and the spit where the treasure is only about 100m long. Happy digging.)

Credit:

 I needed help in several situations and helpful commenters have provided it: matt_rule started the solving with a partial answer about Conway's game of life. Stiv decoded the HSM code as a game of Battleships. Finally, Vladimir Cravero decoded the QR code, which I had failed to do.

 And Beastly Gerbil created a fine puzzle with excellent presentation. Thank you.


Aha! I was staring at those three corners, totally confused. Okay, the top part is rot13(n tnzr bs onggyrfuvcf - uvg, fhax, zvff - znlor whfg sbphf ba gur uvgf naq fvaxf? 'FNJ' vf 'fvax naq jva')

(And if you look very closely at the bottom-right corner on each of the snippets there are faint diagrammatic clues as to the content of that bit...)

Also note there are two possible solutions for south depending on how you stack the left-hand side - you may need to try both to see if you have it right...

Great stuff - so close! @Stiv seems to have figured out the rest for you to iron everything out, although I will add for the top part also contains a hidden hint which you no longer need ;)

Ah, thanks for explaining the HMS notation. (If I remember correctly we used to say "jngre" for M.)

@BeastlyGerbil Argh, I'm an idiot - I even noticed that! MOehm - rot13(gur ybfvat grnz'f tevq fcryyf bhg 'DE' va Oenvyyr!) I was attuned to it after a solve yesterday!

@Stiv haha, good at find at least, even if you missed the meaning :P

Haha. At least you're not seeing dots everywhere yet. I'd say you're fine. Let's see how this map bussiness plays out ...

I'm not someone who knows much about QR code validity, but what I do know is my phone scans it fine!

The QR code works fine for me as well. spoiler: https://maps.app.goo.gl/KE8pyeFH5b1S4Gn37
perhaps the answerer has a phone that does not support rot13(puvarfr punenpgref)? Anyway, this puzzle is beautiful & the solution is beautiful too.

The fact that rot13(gur yvaxrq vfynaq'f funcr zngpurf gur pragre bs gur DE pbqr) so exactly is complete genius! I'm not even sure how you managed that.

@VladimirCravero thanks! And that's a good point, but as it has now been decoded I'll provide the text for MOehm on the chance it doesn't work for all phones: @ MOehm the QR decodes to '松浦島 K7'

@canton7 glad you enjoyed :) To tell the truth I started this puzzle 4 years ago and its taken a whilst to finish - I'll probably post a 'the making of' when the answer is fully complete as it was an annoying process to find a QR that worked!

Thanks all for chiming in. Looking back, that's what I got, too, but I thought it was "mojibake". Sorry about that. Will update the post properly later.

This is a remarkable puzzle and methodical answer, both are brilliant! Well done, everyone.

Wrap-up:  The Making Of Is this map real?
This is not a solution to the puzzle, but provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been approved by the community.
Thought I would write a wrap up as there are some interesting points about QR codes that some may definitely find useful in the future!
Caution: This post contain spoilers.

Inspiration
I actually started on this idea 4 years ago. Long time coming!
Back in lockdown, I had the idea to disguise a QR code as a treasure map, and have the QR scan to give a map coordinate, but I could never find anything that really worked. So I gave up, and had completely forgotten about it.
But then a couple of months ago, I redownloaded an old app I used to draw stuff, and my old map was right there!

The old draft is very different, it was many fake islands, and although the art was cute, I didn't have any of the info to finish it off.
But I remembered the concept and knew it was time to do it properly - but this time bigger and better.
Finding a QR code that worked
This time round, I wanted the map to show a real island, that would eventually be the answer itself. That however, was going to be very tricky.
It couldn't be a famous island as that would be pointless, so I needed to find some islands that were small, and 'spiky' - such that you would be able to draw them with squares.
To do so, my first instinct was to go on google maps and have a look around the cposts of some of the countries in Asia, such as Indonesia and Japan, as I felt like they would have the highest likelihood of having what I was looking for.
In my search I also stumbled across this website - containing a list of islands in a region off Japan. The one that immediately caught my eye was number 7 - "Matsuura Island"

It was exactly what I was looking for, but now I needed to encode a QR code to give the name of this island, plus a cell coordinate which would overlap one of the island cells, and also look like the island. Oof.
However, I had a few candidates of island names, the cells could be in the region H8-N14 ish, and I also had the option of using the Japanese names of the island.
I also knew from previous puzzles I'd made, that for the middle of QR codes in particular you can actually change quite a few cells without affecting the text when it is scanned. So the QR code I was looking for didn't have to be perfect, just close enough.
[Turns out, thanks to @Bobson in the comments, that every QR code has one of four levels of error correction, which allows from 7% to 30% of the QR to be changed and still have it recoverable.
This puzzle ended up using the  "L" level (apparently typical for smaller QR codes) which means I could change about 7% of the QR - or about 8 pixels before it became unreadable]

So, using this QR generator as it was quick to update, I started generating hundreds of QRs. I would type for instance "Matsuura H8" and then H9, H10... up to H17 before checking I8, I9...
After a few hundred QRs, I hadn't found anything close enough. So I moved onto the Japanese names of the islands and checked those.
And after maybe 200 more, bingo!* Behold: "松浦島 K7"

Ok it wasn't perfect, but it was damn close. And 'K7' was a valid cell containing the top of the island. Yesssss.
Editing the QR code
To edit the QR code as close as possible to the island, I simply rebuilt it in excel.
I created a bitmap of Matsuura island, as the 'perfect' situation:

However, changing the QR code to this didn't give me a valid QR.
So instead, I changed a cell of the QR code at a time - checking every time that the QR still worked, until finally I reached this for the island:

And the QR still worked!!
Making the puzzle
For the rest of the puzzle, I cut up the remaining sections that weren't part of the puzzle (making sure each had different dimensions), and devised a shortlist of how I could clue them.
The nonogram, coordinates and binary were all very simple to make. Game of life took a bit of trial and error, and the battleships I added the extra hint of 'QR' in braille for the other game.
I then designed the puzzles artwork (which took far too long) in Krita - highly recommend, it is powerful and free. I used google earth to try and make the island look as real as possible.
And just like that, the hard work had paid off!!
Takeaway
Other than the fact you can manipulate QR codes quite a bit without losing the message, there is a good lesson from making this:
This took a lot of perseverance. I knew it was a nice puzzle idea, but first time round I gave up, and second time round it took months, with wayyyyyy too many QRs generated (so many in fact, that the QR site blocked me and I had to come back the next day!) But in the end, I knew it was achievable, and without enough effort it was done...
And I think that can be applied to a lot of the puzzles here - and to life itself!

Hope you all enjoyed and this was helpful/insightful to some! Thanks all for the positive feedback :)

Great write-up for a cool puzzle - you should be proud of the end product :) And I'm going to check out Krita - that one's new to me. Thanks!

@Stiv thanks! :) Yeah first time using it for a puzzle, have used Autodesk Sketchbook for everything till now, but wanted an upgrade and that was the best powerful and free editor I could find - much prefer it over Gimp too

Congratulations on a super puzzle. Too bad I botched the actual revelation. :( I like the presentation ‒ both the graphics and that the story is to the point and lets those enigmatic graphics take centre stage.

(Krita is definitely worth checking out. I want to like it, but I'm not really comfortable with it. I'm probably just not comfortable with my graphics tablet and it's not Krita's fault.)

@MOehm thanks and great solve! Don’t worry about that, completely understandable that you thought the text was a bunch of rubbish, I think I would have to!

As far as editing the QR goes, every QR code has one of four levels of error correction, which allow from 7% to 30% of the QR to be scrambled/missing/hidden and still have it recoverable.  This appears to be "L" level, so you would be able to corrupt ~8 pixels before it becomes unreadable, if I worked it out correctly.

@Bobson ooh thanks, that’s super interesting and helpful! Will edit that in :)

Possibly a tiny part of the answer below (spoilers):

 This is not an answer, but if you take the lower right figure and insert it into a Conway's Game of Life sim, then advance it by one generation, it produces this, which fits inside the 4x5 outline shown in the question. This was inspired by the text saying "Next Gen":


 


 Some more observations: At the top appear to be H and N in a heavy gothic font, it would make sense if this is simply a 21x21 grid with coordinates ranging from A1 in the top left to U21, and K11 in the middle. That leaves a 4x5 space on the left where this Game of Life shape could fit, though that could be coincidental. The top left scrap has what appear to be pairs of coordinates where either X or Y match, so they could be straight lines, though if you plot them all, some overlap. The top right scrap uses [I...M][1..5] / [V..Z][1..5] which all have a range of 5, and H, M, S.


1/5 out of… who knows ;)

Some more observations added to the "answer"

Oh, I can see where this is going ...

@MOehm I'm glad you can, because I feel like I have all 5 sub-puzzles solved but cannot see for the life of me where it goes from there!

I'm just writing an answer, @Stiv. Perhaps you can help me with the northern part, which I'm still missing.
